# eclipse variable substitution before invoking maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Is there a way to tell m2e to resolve eclipse variables before invoking maven? I have this configuration

```xml
<plugin>
    <!-- Done to create Target Platform needed by eclipse -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>

                <outputDirectory>${workspace_loc}/project-OSGi/target/dependency</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But `${workspace_loc}` doesn't get resolved before invoking maven so I end up with a folder called workspace_loc

Comment: What do you mean by "eclipse variables"?

Comment: In the UI they are also called "String Substitution variables". You can find them in Preferences/Run-Debug/String substitutions. Those are the user defined ones, but there are other eclipse variables like "workspace_loc" or "project_loc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion was that it's not possible to resolve eclipse variables before invoking maven. The only workaround I found was using an environment variable in maven `{env.XX}` and eclipse `${env_var:XX}`, that way both maven and eclipse resolve to the same value

Answer (score 0):

I believe `${workspace_loc}` is some CDT-specific Eclipse variable, isn't it?

What you need here is `${project.build.directory}`, which is the `target` directory you need. You could also try a few other options, just type `${` and press *Ctrl+Space*, and it will show you all the usable properties and their actual resolved value as a hint.

Comment: i don't think it's CDT specific. I use it in JDT but 'm pretty sure it's general to eclipse. ${project.build.directory} doesn't work  here because each submodule will copy its dependencies to its own target folder. what i want is a single folder where every maven module copies its dependencies. That's why i was trying something relative to the workspace path, not the project. But still, my question is not about a different maven variable, but about if its possible (and how) to tell m2e to resolve eclipse variables before passing them to maven

Comment: Oh I see... Hm, interesting question. I don't think that's possible (Maven should not now anything about the IDE because it would break the build process in command line or in any other IDEs). What is possible though is using some properties you can set under the run configuration.